# WordPress add_submenu_page gives incorrect url

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a bug I can't seem to resolve.
I have this line in a statically written class:

```
add_submenu_page( 
    'ib_inbound_main',
    'Analyics Configuration',
    'Analytics',
    'edit_pages',
    'ib_analytics_config',
    array ('ib_analytics_admin_panels', 'render_config_panel')
);
```

Which is generating this link:

```
<a href="ib_analytics_config" class="wp-first-item">Analytics</a>
```

Which is missing `admin.php?page=`
Can anyone see why this is occurring?

Answer (score 11):

The reason the URL was generated incorrectly is because I was trying to create the submenu page before the main menu item existed.

It should have been obvious but I was thrown off the scent because the menu appeared to otherwise generate correctly - I thought that building the admin menus out of sequence would have white screened WordPress.